# Can't find column from SQLite after insert

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Inside class `DataBaseSqlite` I use `DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT` inside method `onCreate` to create database.

```
package DataBaseSqlite;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by jur_1 on 02-Apr-17.
 */

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    //CLIENT VARIABLES
    public static final String TABLE_CLIENT = "clients";
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "rowid ";
    public static final String CLIENT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CLIENT_CONTACT_ID = "contactId";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "JurBankTransactions.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;


    //CLIENT TABLE
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT = "create table " + TABLE_CLIENT + "( " + CLIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
            + CLIENT_NAME + " text not null, " + CLIENT_CONTACT_ID + " text not null)";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TRANSACTIONS = "create table transactions( _id integer key auto increment, clientID integer, typeID integer, debt integer, quantity integer, date text)";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TYPE = "create table types( _id integer key auto increment, name text not null)";


    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TRANSACTIONS);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clients");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transactions");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS types");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

After that inside **MainActivity** I call intent which opens Contacts and retrive data about the contact that users selects. Then I call method **createClient** which is located inside class **CliendDataSource** inside which **cursorToClient** is called and I cant' retrive contactId value.

```
package CustomListView;

/**
 * Created by jur_1 on 10-May-17.
 */

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import DataBaseSqlite.Client;
import DataBaseSqlite.MySQLiteHelper;

public class ClientDataSource
{
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    private String[] allColumns = {MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_ID, MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_NAME};

    public ClientDataSource(Context context)
    {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException
    {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Client createClient(String name, String contactId)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_NAME, name);
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
        Log.d("CREATE_CLIENT", "values contact id: " + contactId);
        Log.d("CREATE_CLIENT", "values length: " + values.size());
        long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CLIENT, null,
                values);
        System.out.println("new id: " + insertId);
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CLIENT,
                allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Client newClient = cursorToClient(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newClient;
    }

    public void deleteClient(Client client)
    {
        long id = client.getId();
        System.out.println("Client deleted with id: " + id);
        database.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CLIENT, MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_ID
                + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public List<Client> getAllClients()
    {
        List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CLIENT,
                allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Client client = cursorToClient(cursor);
                clients.add(client);
                cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
        return clients;
    }

    private Client cursorToClient(Cursor cursor)
    {
        Log.d("cursorToClient", "cursor num of columsn: " + cursor.getColumnCount());
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        Log.d("cursorToClient", "column id: " + cursor.getLong(0));
        client.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        Log.d("cursorToClient", "cursor name: " + cursor.getString(1));
        String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();
        for(String columnName : columnNames)
        {
            System.out.println("Column: " + columnName);
        }
        Log.d("cursorToClient", "column name 2: " + cursor.getColumnName(2));
        client.setContactsId(cursor.getString(2));
        return client;
    }
}
```

Output of log is:

```
19:32.067 8647-8647/com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank D/cursorToClient: cursor num of columsn: 2
05-12 22:19:32.068 8647-8647/com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank D/cursorToClient: column id: 1
05-12 22:19:32.068 8647-8647/com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank D/cursorToClient: cursor name: Alen Ban
05-12 22:19:32.068 8647-8647/com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank I/System.out: Column: rowid
05-12 22:19:32.068 8647-8647/com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank I/System.out: Column: name
```

Error:

```
05-12 22:19:32.069 8647-8647/com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank, PID: 8647
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/549i30872f420c7a3b2e.1115i91.1419r1625-293F31432B2943/95 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank/com.jurbank.jurbank.jurbank.MainActivityClients}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
```

Comment: what are the logs output?

Comment: Are you deleting the database (e.g. settings/apps clear data) or changing the version number after making changes? The `onCreate` method will only be called if the database doesn't exist (or you specifically call it). Alternately changing the version number would delete the tables and call `onCreate`. P.S. you probably do not want AUTOINCREMENT (as per _he AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed._ see https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Comment: @MikeT If I make changes to database I just delete and install app again, but I also tried increasing the version number of database. 
What should I use instead of AUTOINCREMENT for rowid, so that every new row has a new rowid?

Comment: @jure just use `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, and as long as you don't specify a value for rowid when inserting a row then a unique (to the table) id will automatically be set (normally 1 greater than the last). i.e. simply remove the  AUTOINCREMENT keyword and it should work the same.

Comment: @MikeT ok, thank you. Do you have any other idea what could be wrong with table columns?

Comment: I'm looking into that now. Just about to try first run based upon your code.

Comment: @Jur try changing `public static final String CLIENT_ID = "rowid ";` to `public static final String CLIENT_ID = "rowid";` i.e. removing the space after **rowid**. You'll need to clear the App's data. Basically, other than this my testing worked.

Comment: @MikeT I cleared data and cache after that made uninstall, but still same error.

Comment: I don't think that the issue you have is with the Database. I think that it might be in the Client class. the actual error indicates that an Array is out of bounds that is you are trying to access yourarray[2] when there are only 2 elements i.e yourarray[0] and yourarray[1] exist. I think you need to look at and perhaps post the Client class. especially look at the `setContactsId` method. However, it is surprising that `Log.d("cursorToClient", "collumn name 2: " + cursor.getColumnName(2));` didn't output anything. So perhaps remove the loop doing the `system.out` to see if that's the issue.

Comment: @jur, just added the system.out loop and ran. It ran OK BUT I get 3 columns output. Seeing you only get 2 the indication is that there are perhaps only two columns. You haven't by any chance subscribed to some google backup? If I recall correctly someone was having issues with that automatically restoring a deleted database). trying using a different DB name.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your statement `DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT`. May be column `CLIENT_CONTACT_ID` not being added due to missing `space` before end `")"`.

**Update your create table `statement` as below:**

```
//CLIENT TABLE
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CLIENT + "( " + CLIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
        + CLIENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + CLIENT_CONTACT_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL )";
```

Also remove space from column name `CLIENT_ID`.

**Use:**

```
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "rowid";
```

**Instead of:**

```
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "rowid ";
```

Finally `uninstall` & `install` again your application.

Hope this will help~

Comment: I added whole method where I use INSERT.

Comment: make sure the contactId not null

Comment: When I output it in the log, it's not null.

Comment: can you please post your full class?

Comment: Now I posted both classes, without MainAcitvity or do you also need that? I hope that there is not to much code now.

Comment: Have you tried with hard coded values? values.put(MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_NAME, "Android");
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_CONTACT_ID, "1234");

Comment: I tried hard codded values and updated answer, but I still have the same problem. And I also uninstalled app so that database was deleted.

Comment: use private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CLIENT + "( " + CLIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
        + CLIENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + CLIENT_CONTACT_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL )";         and try again

Comment: Thank your for your help, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm sure of the problem but the following, based upon your code, works. I did have an issue (as per comment in Ferdous's post) with "rowid " having the space. However, this was with using the variable being passed to `getColumnIndex()` i.e. with the space it returned -1 (not found).

Anyway here's some code that works for me which is very much based upon your code (less the Client class stuff):-

The DBHelper (with `addClient` and `getAllClients` for testiing) :-

```
public class DBHelperClients extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //CLIENT VARIABLES
    public static final String TABLE_CLIENT = "clients";
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "rowid";
    public static final String CLIENT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CLIENT_CONTACT_ID = "contactId";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "JurBankTransactions.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;


    //CLIENT TABLE
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT = "create table " + TABLE_CLIENT +
            "( " + CLIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + CLIENT_NAME + " text not null, "
            + CLIENT_CONTACT_ID + " text not null)";

    public DBHelperClients(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_CLIENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {

    }

    public long addClient(String name, String contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(CLIENT_NAME,name);
        cv.put(CLIENT_CONTACT_ID,contact);
        return db.insert(TABLE_CLIENT,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllClients() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(TABLE_CLIENT,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

The invoking activity is as follows :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //DBHelper db;
    DBHelperClients db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DBHelperClients(this);
        db.addClient("Fred","email");
        db.addClient("Bert","snailmail");
        db.addClient("Harry","smoke signals");

        Cursor myclients = db.getAllClients();
        while (myclients.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("MYCLIENT","Client name=" +
                    myclients.getString(myclients.getColumnIndex(DBHelperClients.CLIENT_NAME)) +
                    "\tClient Contact=" +
                    myclients.getString(myclients.getColumnIndex(DBHelperClients.CLIENT_CONTACT_ID)) +
                    "\tID=" + Long.toString(myclients.getLong(myclients.getColumnIndex(DBHelperClients.CLIENT_ID)))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The log (after 2nd run, so duplicate data) :-

```
05-13 18:49:16.058 7260-7260/mjt.testvcsuse D/MYCLIENT: Client name=Fred    Client Contact=email    ID=1
05-13 18:49:16.058 7260-7260/mjt.testvcsuse D/MYCLIENT: Client name=Bert    Client Contact=snailmail    ID=2
05-13 18:49:16.058 7260-7260/mjt.testvcsuse D/MYCLIENT: Client name=Harry   Client Contact=smoke signals    ID=3
05-13 18:49:16.058 7260-7260/mjt.testvcsuse D/MYCLIENT: Client name=Fred    Client Contact=email    ID=4
05-13 18:49:16.058 7260-7260/mjt.testvcsuse D/MYCLIENT: Client name=Bert    Client Contact=snailmail    ID=5
05-13 18:49:16.058 7260-7260/mjt.testvcsuse D/MYCLIENT: Client name=Harry   Client Contact=smoke signals    ID=6
```

Subtle differences, that shouldn't have resolved any issue are

I've used `while(cursor.moveToNext()) {}` to loop through the cursor and instead of using specific offsets for columns when getting data from the cursor. I've used `cursor.getColumnIndex(name of the column)` which is more flexible.

Perhaps try using the above, see if it works and then adapt it for your needs.

Comment: If the above isn't helpful then perhaps edit the original post to include the Client class.

Comment: I found my error. I don't know if I should accept your or @Ferdous answer or add my own. Problem was in this line:
private String[] allColumns = {MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_ID, MySQLiteHelper.CLIENT_NAME};

This is used in query and should return all the collumns in the row, but when I added contact_id to table, I didn't add it here. So query always returned just two rows.

Comment: @Jure OMG, very interesting issue `allColumns`. I have learned a lot from your question :)

Comment: @FerdousAhamed I don't know if this is bad design, but I followed this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: If you need some specific column values then you can try this way otherwise you can use "SELECT * FROM TABLE"